# Password validate with vuelidate in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got the reference from [How to validate password with Vuelidate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176720/how-to-validate-password-with-vuelidate)

```js
 validations: {

    user: {
      password: { required, 
        containsUppercase: function(value) {
          return /[A-Z]/.test(value)
        },
        containsLowercase: function(value) {
          return /[a-z]/.test(value)
        },
        containsNumber: function(value) {
          return /[0-9]/.test(value)
        },
        containsSpecial: function(value) {
          return /[#?!@$%^&*-]/.test(value)
        },
        
        
        minLength: minLength(8),maxLength: maxLength(19) },
      confirmPassword: { required, sameAsPassword: sameAs("password") },
    }, 
    }
```

```html
<input
                  :type="passwordFieldType"
                  v-model="user.password"
                  v-model.trim="$v.user.password.$model"
                  id="password"
                  name="password"
                  class="input-section-three-login"
                  :class="{'is-invalid': validationStatus($v.user.password) }"                  
                  placeholder="Enter new password"
                  :maxlength="maxpassword" 
                  v-on:keypress="isPassword($event)"

                />
                
                
 <button v-on:click="registerMe" :disabled="user.confirmPassword != user.password   " :class="(isDisabled) ? '' : 'selected'" > Register
</button>
```

How to validate the password with vuelidate, i am having regex value in validationStatus and on button click how to check the regex validation.

Trying for if password is validated success with regex validation, move to next screen else till success he need to stay in current screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below steps to resolve the issue

Step 1: `validations` modified like below

```
validations: {
user: {
  password: { required, 
    valid: function(value) {
      const containsUppercase = /[A-Z]/.test(value)
      const containsLowercase = /[a-z]/.test(value)
      const containsNumber = /[0-9]/.test(value)
      const containsSpecial = /[#?!@$%^&*-]/.test(value)
      return containsUppercase && containsLowercase && containsNumber && containsSpecial
    },
    minLength: minLength(9),
    maxLength: maxLength(19),
  },
  confirmPassword: { required, sameAsPassword: sameAs("password") },
},
},
```

Step 2: `RegisterMe` button click event

```
methods: {
registerMe() {
  this.submitted = true;
  this.$v.$touch();
  if (this.$v.$invalid) {
    return false; // stop here if form is invalid
  } else {
    alert("Form Valid. Move to next screen");
  }
},
},
```

Step 3: `compute` function to disable `Register` button

```
computed: {
isDisabled() {
  return this.$v.$invalid;
},
},
```

Step 4: HTML template be like

```
<form @submit.prevent="registerMe" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input
      type="password"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Enter Password"
      value=""
      v-model="user.password"
      autocomplete="off"
    />
    <div
      v-if="this.submitted && $v.user.password.$error"
      class="invalid-feedback left">
      <span v-if="!$v.user.password.required">Password is required</span>
      <span v-if="user.password && !$v.user.password.valid">Password contains atleast One Uppercase, One Lowercase, One Number and One Special Chacter</span>
      <span v-if="user.password && $v.user.password.valid && !$v.user.password.minLength">Password must be minimum 9 characters</span>
      <span v-if="user.password && !$v.user.password.maxLength">Password must be maximum 19 characters</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input
      type="password"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Confirm Password"
      value=""
      v-model="user.confirmPassword"
      autocomplete="off"
    />
    <div
      v-if="this.submitted && $v.user.confirmPassword.$error"
      class="invalid-feedback left"
    >
      <span v-if="!$v.user.confirmPassword.required"
        >Confirm Password is required</span
      >
      <span
        v-if="
          user.confirmPassword && !$v.user.confirmPassword.sameAsPassword
        "
        >Password and Confirm Password should match</span
      >
    </div>
  </div>
  <input
    type="submit"
    class="btnRegister"
    value="Register"
    :disabled="this.isDisabled"
  />
</form>
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-worker-vkfix)

Comment: Its working fine but, In the Register button, i have :disabled="user.confirmPassword != user.password. and  :disabled="this.isDisabled"

Comment: How can i merge both conditions together to satisfy both the conditions

Comment: @santoshchandu You dont wants to validate other form fields then remove from validation. Once the form is valid then button will be automatically enabled otherwise it will be disabled.

Comment: @santoshchandu Register button you should have only one disable confitions :disabled="this.isDisabled". No need to do the validation again for checking password and confirm passwords are same. Validation condition will taken care your validations.

Comment: @santoshchandu Check the full code and demo link too