# Problem while changing button color if password and confirmpassword fields are matched in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
password: '',
confirmPassword: '',

computed: {
    empty() {
      return this.user.password === '' || this.user.confirmPassword === '';
    },
    equal() {
      return this.user.password === this.user.confirmPassword;
    }
  }
```

```css
 .empty {
          width: 160px;
          height: 50px;
          line-height: 50px;
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 16px;
          font-weight: 600;
          color: #fff;
          background-color: #f68e91;
          border-radius: 10px;
          margin-top: 15px;
          padding: 0 20px;
          cursor: pointer;
          opacity: 0.5; 
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          outline: none;
          border: none;
        }
        
        .no-empty {
          opacity: 1.5;
background-color: #ee1d24;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="user.password" type="text">
  <input v-model="user.confirmPassword" type="text">
  <button  :class="[empty ? 'empty' : 'no-empty']" :disabled="empty">Send</button>
</div>
```

For the above code, i am able to change color of button  if fields are empty, and if  filled are not empty changing color.

But issue is in the confirmPassword field if i enter single character only it is changing color of button.I need as if password and confirm password is match only change button color, else different color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1** - With in template styling without functions

Step 1: HTML template will be

```
<div id="app">
<input v-model="user.password" type="text" />
<input v-model="user.confirmPassword" type="text" />
<button :class="user.password && user.confirmPassword && user.password === user.confirmPassword  ? 'match' : 'nomatch'" :disabled="empty">
  Send
</button>
```

Step 2: Scripts will be

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      user: {
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: "",
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    empty() {
      return this.user.password === "" && this.user.confirmPassword === "";
    },
  },
};
```

Step 3: Styles like below

```
<style>
.nomatch {
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f68e91;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.match {
  opacity: 1.5;
  background-color: #ee1d24;
}
</style>
```

**Approach 2** - HTML template With function handler

Step 1: HTML template like below

```
<div id="app">
<input v-model="user.password" type="text" />
<input v-model="user.confirmPassword" type="text" />
<button :class="this.matchPassword() ? 'match' : 'nomatch'" :disabled="empty">
  Send
</button>
```

Step 2: Scripts will be

```
  <script>
  export default {
    name: "App",
    data() {
      return {
        user: {
          password: "",
          confirmPassword: "",
        },
      };
    },
    computed: {
      empty() {
        return this.user.password === "" && this.user.confirmPassword === "";
      },
    },
    methods: {
      matchPassword() {
        if (
          this.user.password &&
          this.user.confirmPassword &&
          this.user.password === this.user.confirmPassword
        ) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

Step 3: Styles

```
<style>
.nomatch {
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f68e91;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.match {
  opacity: 1.5;
  background-color: #ee1d24;
}
</style>
```

Both the approaches will works fine. Please find the demo link below

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-germain-csh9i)

Comment: Its working fine, I am having  :disabled="user.password && !$v.user.password.valid  ||
       user.confirmPassword && !$v.user.confirmPassword.sameAsPassword  "  where it will check for alphanumeric regex conditions if matching only it will proceed

Comment: Now from the Aapproach1 code, if i enter aaaa and aaaa button color is changing,Now from the above change , if i enter aaaa and aaaa button color is changing. But want to proceed if :disabled="user.password && !$v.user.password.valid || user.confirmPassword && !$v.user.confirmPassword.sameAsPassword " if this matches

Comment: @taneerudhanunjay both passwords are matching then we are changing the button color.

Comment: @taneerudhanunjay Check the link below. This is what you wanted? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66688532/password-validate-with-vuelidate-in-vuejs/66689801#66689801

Comment: What i am supposed to do is, If i try to enter any random equal password, then   color will be empty, And if it Only alphanumeric values then non-empty.

I have updated my code, Can you please check, it will be really helpful for me. Thanks 

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-moon-mw43w?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: @taneerudhanunjay I created new demo link. https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-password-validation-sdzjk. Hope this would resolve your issue. If it helps you give a Thumbs Up to the answer. Check the link and let me know.

Comment: @taneerudhanunjay Did my solutions works for you?

Comment: @taneerudhanunjay Its my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the color to only change if both password values are non empty and equal, correct?

If so, your ternary condition only evaluates `empty` not `equal`. Just update the condition in your template:

```html
<button :class="[empty || !equal ? 'empty' : 'no-empty']" :disabled="empty">Send</button>
```

You can also update the `:disabled` attribute condition the same way if you want.

Comment: What i am supposed to do is, If i try to enter any random equal password, then   color will be empty, And if it Only alphanumeric values then non-empty.

I have updated my code, Can you please check, it will be really helpful for me. Thanks

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-moon-mw43w?file=/src/App.vue